# get JSONArray value from key in Multimap

Tags: java, collections, multimap

I have a multimap.

```
Multimap<String,JSONArray> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

I am trying to get all values based from key. But when I am trying, I am getting the following error:

```
 Exception details:  java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap$RandomAccessWrappedList cannot be 
 cast to org.json.JSONArray
 java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultimap$RandomAccessWrappedList cannot be 
 cast to org.json.JSONArray
```

I am trying to do :

```
for (final String str : map.keySet()) {
            final JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) map.get(str);
           //do something
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to get the jsonArray for each keyset?

Comment: What type is `skillSetMap`? How are you populating it?

Comment: @shmosel sorry thats just a map.corrected the question.

Comment: Just a map or a multimap? Do you understand how multimaps work?

Comment: i mean to say its a multimap but the variable name is map.

Comment: Again, do you understand how multimaps work? What do you think [`Multimap.get()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#get-K-) returns?

Comment: @shmosel yes i believe i have the correct understanding.It returns in the the form of list for the same key as we are using keyset.

Comment: Then why would you try to cast it to `JSONArray`?

Comment: Okay basically it returns a collection which i am trying to save it in JSONArray. Such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through values of Multimap like this.

```
  for (Object value1 : map.values()) {
    JSONArray  val  = (JSONArray) value1;
  }
```